# Xcode debug build vs release build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, expo

I am currently building a react native app using expo.

However, I needed to use cocoapods, which is why I am now using Xcode.

Since I have switched to Xcode, there has been a difference between my local debugging builds (that I run to a USB connected iPhone) vs the builds that get pushed to TestFlight.

After doing some digging I have found that it may be due to the [debug vs release schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893951/ios-app-working-on-simulator-but-not-over-testflight) in Xcode.

From what I've see it seems that the [difference should really just be in performance, file sizes, and some other aspects,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270586/xcode-difference-between-debug-and-release) but not what the app actually does and displays like in my case.

To test, I made a change on my app's homepage to simply have the text, `UPDATED`.

As expected, when ran with the debug scheme, the `UPDATED` text shows up, but when ran with the release scheme, it does not.

**How do I get these to sync up and have the release build recognize the changes I make as I am certain I do not want to push a debug build to the app store?**

Things I have tried:

- Removing/cleaning Build folder and rebuilding
- Updating Xcode
- Running on another device
- Building/running with expo (this did something, but it just causes the app to crash, assuming it is because of the cocoapods)

Versions:

- `react-native: 0.61.5`
- `Xcode: 11.4.1`
- `macOS: 10.15.3`

**Thank you**

Comment: A backtrace for the crash might help to diagnose

Comment: So the crash, was only when I built with expo, when running/building with Xcode it runs fine, but the release build does not recognize changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

I found that by running `expo publish` in the terminal and then building with the release archive scheme in Xcode, it notices the changes.

Now why that is required (maybe it isn't), I am unsure of.

If anyone has an any additional insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So it looks like when I run `expo publish` it updates the `app.bundle` and `app.manifest`. This must be what the `release` scheme looks at when building.